# Is there a free PlayReady server available?

Tags: drm, smooth-streaming, playready

I am trying to do an experiment with encrypted Microsoft smooth streaming streams.
And i have a IIS server with transform manager installed. However, i wonder is there a free PlayReady server available online for testing?

It can be a trial or functionality limited version.
I just want to do a quick POC before invest more into this.

I found a service provider list on Microsoft PlayReady site: http://www.microsoft.com/playready/licensing/asp/

But none of them seems to provide any form of free trial.

Does anybody know any service i can use? or is there an alternative way of applying DRM to smooth streaming?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks all for the answers, and thanks to [Sander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2928/sander), i have actually found one usable:
http://playready.directtaps.net/pr/doc/slee/

FYI

Comment: Looks like there isn't. But you can easily build up you own local one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A time-limited free trial of [SilverHD DRM](http://axinom.com/drm) is available for commercial users - the contact details to get a trial account are on the website. The free trial includes access to a PlayReady and Windows Media DRM license server and all the licensing related functionality that goes along with that. *Disclaimer: I work for Axinom who provides the SilverHD DRM service.*

Alternatively, Microsoft has a [public PlayReady test server](http://playready.directtaps.net/pr/doc/customrights/) that you can use for free. Basically, it will always provide a persistent license in response to any license request made to it. Not very flexible and the URL query string customization options tend to not actually work, but maybe it suits your needs?

If you describe your needs in more detail, I might be able to offer more specific advice on how to proceed with evaluating PlayReady.

Comment: Thanks! i found that http://playready.directtaps.net/pr/doc/slee/ is just what i need, all i need is to do some POC hack on a DRM protected smooth streaming media stream

Answer (score 1):

2019-01-09 update:
New Microsoft Test Playready Server can be used for testing. Please note this does not secure keys as it's given in laurl request(base64). See example below.

```
kid=43215678123412341234123412341234
key=12341234123412341234123412341234
playready=https://test.playready.microsoft.com/service/rightsmanager.asmx?cfg=(kid:header,sl:2000,persist:false,firstexp:60,contentkey:EjQSNBI0EjQSNBI0EjQSNA==)
```

(edit 2019-06-06) License url for older devices without a time-policy feature drop firstexp attribute.

`playready=https://test.playready.microsoft.com/service/rightsmanager.asmx?cfg=(kid:header,sl:2000,persist:false,contentkey:EjQSNBI0EjQSNBI0EjQSNA==)`

Answer (score 0):

I must admit I've not looked closely at this but have you checked out Azure [Media Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/media-services/)? 
They have a free trial and it looks like they [support PlayReady and a bunch of other things](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/media-services/).

Doesn't look like they have a "portal" at the moment ([coming in future release](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/MediaServices/thread/431ef036-0939-4784-a939-0ecb31151ded)), so you have to do the uploading etc. with code.

Comment: Windows Azure Media Services does not currently offer a PlayReady server, it just enables you to encrypt content you encode there.

Comment: Hi, Azure Media Services currently support PlayReady license service,you could easily configure one for testing purpose: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/09/10/announcing-public-availability-of-azure-media-services-content-protection-services/

Answer (score 0):

Here are some test streams you could use to test your PlayReady implementation:

PlayReady Encrypted Smooth Streaming:http://htmlsamples.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/66446cae-fd27-4c8f-a1c2-a38a9771ac09/Testing.ism/Manifest

PlayReady Encrypted HLS: http://htmlsamples.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/66446cae-fd27-4c8f-a1c2-a38a9771ac09/Testing.ism/Manifest(format=m3u8-aapl)

PlayReady Encrypted DASH: http://htmlsamples.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/66446cae-fd27-4c8f-a1c2-a38a9771ac09/Testing.ism/Manifest(format=mpd-time-csf)

Here is how you could configure PlayReady license server on Azure with a few steps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k6WWfZxE42w

This is a blog post for PlayReady and AES key service via Azure Media Services: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/01/29/azure-media-services-enhances-streaming-security-with-general-availability-of-drm-technology/

Please reach out to yanmf@microsoft if you have any questions.

Comment: These test streams are no longer there, any chance you could make them available again?

Comment: How do I download PlayReady Server SDK? I tried to find it, but still today not found. Please help me in this.